# Splt Datatable Rows in two column after fixed numer of rows

Tags: c#, datatable, split

I'm preparing print report with GridView, for now I am populating data from Database in her brut format (Two Column (ID, Name))

> ID  Name 
>   ==========
>   1     x1
>   2     x3
>   3     x4
>   4     x8

Manager request to print data in two column which mean

> ID    Name   ID   Name
>   =======================
>   1      x1    3    x4
>   2      x3    4    x8

Code:

```
static DataTable GetData() 
{ 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    dt.Columns.Add(
        new DataColumn("ID", typeof(Int32))
    ); 
    dt.Columns.Add(
        new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string))); 

    for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++) 
    { 
        DataRow Row = dt.NewRow(); 
        Row["ID"] = i; 
        Row["Name"] = "Name " + i.ToString(); 
        dt.Rows.Add(Row); } return dt; 
    }
}
```

Is there any solution to split datatable to two column .

Regards

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can we see some code please.

Comment: What exactly are your conditions that determine what goes into the second set of columns? Is it after a certain number of rows, when it hits a certain value, what?

Comment: @sr28 Hi, the condition is after a fixed number of rows. Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried so far?

Comment: @sr28 no special code, just fill a datatable and put the GridView DataSource to the filled datatable ` static DataTable GetData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(Int32)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
            {
                DataRow Row = dt.NewRow();
                Row["ID"] = i;
                Row["Name"] = "Name " + i.ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(Row);
            }
            return dt;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 :

```
        DataTable dtFull = GetData();

        DataTable newDt = new DataTable();

        newDt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(String));
        newDt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
        newDt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(String));
        newDt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));

        for (int i = 0; i < dtFull.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow newrow = newDt.NewRow();
            if (i * 2  < dtFull.Rows.Count)
            {
                newrow["ID"] = dtFull.Rows[i * 2][0].ToString();
                newrow["Name"] = dtFull.Rows[i * 2][1].ToString();
                newDt.Rows.Add(newrow);
            }

            if (i*2+1 < dtFull.Rows.Count)
            {
                newDt.Rows[i][2] = dtFull.Rows[i * 2 + 1][0].ToString();
                newDt.Rows[i][3] = dtFull.Rows[i * 2 + 1][1].ToString();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 (Step Parametre page line count):

```
        DataTable dtFull = GetData();

        DataTable newDt = new DataTable();

        newDt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(String));
        newDt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
        newDt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(String));
        newDt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String));
        bool exit = true;
        int pagecount = 10;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int m = 0;
        while (exit)
        {


            for (j = 0; (j<pagecount);j++)
            {
                DataRow newrow = newDt.NewRow();

                newrow["ID"] = dtFull.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                newrow["Name"] = dtFull.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                newDt.Rows.Add(newrow);

                i++;
                m++;
                if (i >= dtFull.Rows.Count)
                {
                    exit = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (exit)
            {
                k = m - pagecount;
                for (j = 0; (j < pagecount); j++)
                {
                    newDt.Rows[m - pagecount + j][2] = dtFull.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                    newDt.Rows[m - pagecount + j][3] = dtFull.Rows[i][1].ToString();

                    i++;
                    if (i >= dtFull.Rows.Count)
                    {

                        exit = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }      



        }
```